# How to patch node.js server for CVE-2014-0224 on ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, security, ubuntu, ssl

I recently realized that our servers were vulnerable to [CVE-2014-0224](https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20140605.txt) by doing an SSL Labs [scan](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html).

We are running a node.js server on our site.  I [read](http://nodejs.org/changelog.html) that the vulnerability was eliminated in node.js version `0.10.29`, so I used `nvm` to install version `0.11.13` on our ubuntu 12 server.  However, after restarting the node.js server, the scan still shows we're vulnerable.

Thinking that perhaps node.js was relying on the system installation of openssl rather than using their own, I upgraded that, as well.  `openssl version -b` now shows that we have the version that was built on 1 Oct 2014 ... which should be plenty good by all accounts (upgrading to this version was how I eliminated the vulnerability from another one of our servers that was running a ruby server ... also on ubuntu 12).

However, I haven't been able to find the right combination to eliminate the vulnerabilty from our node.js server.  How can I do that?  :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha!  I updated one node.js version later (`0.11.14`), and that solved the problem.  No more vulnerabilities for me!  :o)

Comment: you should be aware that 0.11 is not necessarily better than 0.10. 0.11 is the unstable branch of development, 0.10 is the stable branch. I would upgrade to the latest version of 0.10 before using 0.11 in production.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @Vadim.  I will switch back to 0.10.